# Как прекратить слушать микрофон?

Tags: python, аудио, распознавание-речи

У меня есть короткий код. Всё работает, если что-то сказать - это выведется, но я не понимаю, почему он слушает долго? Когда я сказал уже секунд 5-10 назад. Можно ли как-то завершить прослушивание?

```
import speech_recognition as sr


r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone(device_index=2) as source:
    print("Скажите что ниудь")
    audio = r.listen(source)

voice = r.recognize_google(audio, language="ru-RU")
print("Вы сказали:" + voice.lower())

if voice == "Привет":
    print("Привет")
```

Comment: Этот ответ почитайте https://stackoverflow.com/a/32753416/8324991

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В [документации](https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/1.5.0/) много разных советов. Можно попробовать сразу задрать повыше уровень, на котором распознаётся голос:

```
# это максимум, попробуйте разные значения от 50 до 4000
r.energy_threshold = 4000
```

Можно попробовать отключить динамический режим:

```
# по умолчанию он включен, т.е. True
r.dynamic_energy_threshold = False
```

Там есть и другие параметры, которыми можно поиграться. Главное сначала понять, в чём проблема. Я так понимаю, в вашем случае фоновый шум принимается за речь, т.е. высокая чувствительность микрофона, либо высокий уровень шума. Нужно исходить из этого при подборе параметров. В документации это обозначено как "The recognizer tries to recognize speech even when I’m not speaking." например.

Comment: r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)

Answer (score -1):

Во первых в if надо сравнивать voice с "привет" так как ты сделал voice.lower()
А после слушания до if напиши r.close()
Должно сработать!!!

Comment: Насчёт первого спасибо, но прослушивание всё равно не завершается, ну, точнее завершается ошибкой: `AttributeError: 'Recognizer' object has no attribute 'close'`

Comment: контекст менеджер сделает close когда пройдет дальше